# If $ G(x)= -\int_1^x{\rm} sin \left({t^3}+t\right)dt $ find $G''(x)$

Tags: integration

I don't have much experience with the following... So I don't know how to start solving this. How do I evaluate the following integrals? Any advice, hint or well-thought solution will be appreciated.

If =  $ G(x)= -\int_1^x{\rm} sin \left({t^3}+t\right)dt $ find $G''(x)$

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the integral to compute $G''(x)$. Just exploit the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that to find $G''(x)$ I would take the following steps.

Now consider: $$G(x)= -\int_1^x{\rm} sin \left({t^3}+t\right)dt $$

when we solve this: We will exploit the fundamental theorem of calculus.

$$G'(x) = -sin\left({x^3 + x}\right)$$

hence $G''(x)$ will be ;

$$G''(x)= -\left({3x^2}+1\right) cos\left({x^3}+x\right) $$

Hope this helps you.